# How Symfony routing works

Tags: php, apache, nginx, routes, port

I am a beginner for Symfony and following the Symfony documentation and it has [a create page tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html) 
and after creating this this when I test this using the browser,

I can access it using the following URLs

localhost:8000/lucky/number and

localhost:8000/app_dev.php/lucky/number

but when I try to access it using the usual way like

localhost/appname/lucky/number

it gives 404 and I use Ubuntu with Apache2 localhost so I need to know the idea behind this Symfony3 routing and why I cannot access the page using usual **localhost/cmstest/lucky/number**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html), this is how your vhost should looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MySymfonyProject/web
    <Directory /var/www/MySymfonyProject/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/MySymfonyProject/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/MySymfonyProject_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/MySymfonyProject_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now that you have a clean `vhost`, here are some details/instructions:

- All terminal commands are done as admin (sudo).
- In terminal, run this command `a2enmod rewrite`
- In terminal, as you don't use any URL, make sure to disable the default vhost `a2dissite 000-default.conf`
- In terminal, make sure to enable your site vhost `a2ensite myVhost.conf`
- Make sure your project directory is right `/var/www/MySymfonyProject`
- In terminal, restart apache service with `service apache2 restart`
- Access your site through `localhost` or `localhost/app_dev.php` (you don't have to specify the bundle name)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to use the `web/` directory (which is the public root of your application, only this directory should be accessible using the browser).

When using `server:run`, it'll use `web/` as your server root automatically. When accessing via the directory structure, include it in the URL: `http://localhost/appname/web/lucky/number`

Comment: Thanks for this. useful :))

Answer (score 0):

Hewwo PM-Riabel~

Can you paste here your virtual-host config?
Your first problem may be in it...

Do you have only one virtual-host active on your machine?

I would guess you try to view it from Linux (correct me if it's not the case)
You should set a fictive URL to your hosts file (myurl.com) and redirect it to 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
Then you can configure your virtual-host to work with this same URL. (Better do it when you want to work multiple projects)

Cordially,
Preciel.

Comment: Bellow you can see the file and I do not have any Vhosts                                                      `<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet`

Comment: What you did paste is what we call a vhost... it's writen at the first line `<virtualHost>`